# Advanced search using and

Tags: advanced-search

Hello my search builder is out of action and I’m trying to use advanced search to give me everyone in group A and group B - in the section above (search settings)  the ‘and’ radio button is selected. But the search results are an “or” set not an “and” set. Is it possible to do this in advanced search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the AND OR operators you're referring to only control the relationship between different criteria (i.e. contained in X group AND had an activity of a certain type) not more than one option in the same criteria.

A workaround for sure but perhaps you could add all contacts from one of the groups to a tag and try searching all the belong to group A AND the newly created tag.

Comment: Great - thanks your work around was spot on - saved me having to export both sets off and match them offline